# Seaborn subpots - share x axis between line and bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to create 2 stacked charts via Seaborn in a Juyter lab notebook; one of them being a line chart, the other one being a bar chart. Both should share the same x-axis.

```
%matplotlib widget

dt = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'column_x': range(-10,10), 'vals_1': range(10,30), 'vals_2':range(30,50)})

f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)
sns.lineplot(x="column_x", y="vals_1", data=dt, marker="o", ax=axarr[0])
sns.barplot(x="column_x", y="vals_2", data=dt, ax=axarr[1])
```

Problem is - this doesn't seem to actually share the axis. I'm not entirely sure why, my best bet is that the bar plot treats its x-axis as categorical or such.

[image: Example - wrong axis]

Is there any way to properly share the (numerical) x-axis between both plots?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, seaborn treats the x values as catagorical when making the bar plot:

From the [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html):

> This function always treats one of the variables as categorical and draws data at ordinal positions (0, 1, … n) on the relevant axis, even when the data has a numeric or date type.

So, I think the easiest way might be to turn off `sharex`, and roll your own:

```
axarr[0].set_xlim(dt['column_x'].min()-0.5, dt['column_x'].max()+0.5)
axarr[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
```

should make the two axes ranges and tick positions appear the same

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`lineplot` is a numeric plot, while `barplot` is a categorical plot. You may want to replace `lineplot` by `pointplot`, which is a categorical plot as well.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


dt = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'column_x': range(-10,10), 'vals_1': range(10,30), 'vals_2':range(30,50)})

f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)
sns.pointplot(x="column_x", y="vals_1", data=dt, marker="o", ax=axarr[0])
sns.barplot(x="column_x", y="vals_2", data=dt, ax=axarr[1])

plt.show()
```

[image]