# How to separate overlapping violin plots?

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I'd like to have two violin plots together on the same axis but at the same time, avoid overlap. Do you have any idea how I can achieve that?

This is my code:

```
fig, ax0 = plt.subplots()
ax1 = ax0.twinx()

hue_order = np.unique(eyehead_perf['soa'])

sns.violinplot(data=eyehead_perf, x='soa', y='perf_congr', inner='point', gap=1, hue_order=hue_order, ax=ax0, common_norm = True)
sns.violinplot(data=eyehead_perf, x='soa', y='perf_incongr', inner='point', gap=1, hue_order=hue_order, ax=ax1, common_norm = True)
```

You can see the plot as well.

[image]

I'll appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to organize subplots, and have each group of violins in a different subplot. If you define subplots in a 2x1 grid, they will be aligned on the x-axis (can even use `sharex` argument to force the x-axis to be the same), and each have its own y-axis. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55650458/seaborn-subpots-share-x-axis-between-line-and-bar-chart) on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks:

- having two y-axes that are in a similar range, but not equal, makes a plot harder to understand; in that case, a single y-axis is recommended
- `hue_order=` is only looked at by Seaborn when a `hue=` column is used; the `order=` keyword fixes an order of the `x` axis
- by combining the 'perf_congr' and 'perf_incongr' columns into a [long-form](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data) dataframe, the combined column can be used as `hue`

Here is some example code, starting from some dummy test data:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create some dummy test data
np.random.seed(20231108)
eyehead_perf = pd.DataFrame({'soa': np.repeat([20.0, 50.0, 100.0, 200.0, 300.0], 20),
                             'perf_congr': np.random.normal(0.01, 1, 100).cumsum(),
                             'perf_incongr': np.random.normal(0.02, 1, 100).cumsum()})

# combine 'perf_congr' and 'perf_incongr'
long_df = eyehead_perf.melt(id_vars='soa', value_vars=['perf_congr', 'perf_incongr'])
# make the soa column of integer type to remove the ".0" when converted to string
long_df['soa'] = long_df['soa'].astype(int)
x_order = np.unique(long_df['soa'])

fig, ax0 = plt.subplots() 
sns.violinplot(data=long_df, x='soa', y='value', hue='variable',
               order=x_order, hue_order=['perf_congr', 'perf_incongr'],
               inner='point', common_norm=False, ax=ax0)
sns.move_legend(ax0, loc='best', title='')  # remove the legend title
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: comparing two columns in an sns.violinplot]